# wamp 'put online' not working on ethernet lan

Tags: php, apache, networking, wamp

I am developing a web application. I have built all the pages. I am trying to install it on office network connected through ethernet lan. I am testing my web appication using wamp server.
wamp 'put online' working fine when connected to wifi network.I am able to access pages by putting local ip address in browser.
But when connected to ethernet network by doing 'put online' on wamp I am not able to access pages by putting local ip address in browser. Heres my httpd.conf info.

Listen 0.0.0.0:8080

Listen [::0]:8080

onlineoffline tag - don't remove

Require all granted

ServerName localhost:8080

Geeks please help me out..

Comment: You haven't given enough info, and this is a very broad question and not programming related.. but by the sounds of it, your server isn't configured to display to network machines.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using wamp server,you can access pages by putting local IP address in browser, only when server & user are in the same LAN.

Considering you are accessing pages on same machine where server is installed,I will suggest to check your local IP address, while you are on WiFi and Ethernet network(Type "**ipconfig**" in the command prompt and look for "**IPv4** address").

I am sure your local IP address is getting changed while you are switching between WiFi and Ethernet network.So you can access it by current(IPv4) IP address.

On the same machine,you can also access it by ("**127.0.0.1**") IP address.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Ya my local ip is getting changed while switching between wifi to ethernet. But even if I put current local ip address for ethernet network its not able to access page. My public ip for wifi and ethernet network are same though.

Comment: What I need is 'When I am connected to ethernet network and if I start a server using wamp then I should be able to access pages by putting local ip of my ethernet network in the browser.'
I have my ethernet ip 192.169.x.y and my apache working on 8080.
I hope the procedure is to 'put online' on wamp and then putting web address in the browser as '192.168.x.y:8080'

Comment: The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved these three blocks of the IP address space for private Internets:
     10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
     172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
     192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix) .                                           As you mentioned 192.169.x.y must be your public IP address.You need to explain it properly.Are you able to access it using "localhost:8080" & "127.0.0.1:8080"? What is your current local IP address? and what URL you are trying to access??

Comment: Yes.. i am able to access on localhost:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080.. I am sure that my local ip is 192.168.x.y.. my public ip is 117.22.p.q on my ethernet network.. i am trying to access pages on 192.168.x.y:8080..but not working.. same thing worked for me when i am connected to wifi network with local ip 192.168.a.b and with same public ip 117.22.p.q. Plz help me out i need to put it on my office network as early as possible..

Comment: Sorry that i mentioned my local ip 192.169.x.y but its actually 192.168.x.y. It was typing mistake..

Comment: Its working now.. I think there was problem with my firewall and antivirus settings. Thanks for help :-)